# Fetch first item from the value list using (comma) limiter

Tags: php

I have items visually:

```
array(
 0 => '"abc","def",ghi', //"abc","def",ghi is just value. 0----N is the expected array
 1 => '"jkl", ...',
);
```

My actual written code in use is, so this is the concern:

```
array(
 '"abc","def",ghi', //"abc","def",ghi is just value. 0----N is the expected array
 '"jkl", ...',
);
```

I want to fetch **"abc"**, but need to ignore the rest **,"def",ghi**

How would I do that with PHP?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$firstitem=explode(',',$yourarray[0]);
```

or

```
explode(",", $yourarray[0], 2);//to limit the explode so the resulting array does not contain unwanted elements
```

`$firstitem[0]` will contain the first characters of the first element from yourarray including "

Comment: since you only need the first parrt of the comma seperated string it is better to limit the explode like this explode(",", $yourarray[0], 2); otherwise the resulting array will contain more elements then needed!

Comment: if you want to get rid of the "... you can trim the result like this trim($firstitem,'"'); peace!

Comment: Thanks, still having issue that it outputs some strange characters: &#039;abc&#039;. Do you know how to remove that chars? Trim don't help

Comment: Trim did help. I did a reverse of "'. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
$exp = explode(',', $myArray[0]);
print $exp[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$v = array(
 0 => '"abc","def",ghi', //"abc","def",ghi is just value. 0----N is the expected array
 1 => '"jkl", ...',
);

$x = reset(explode(',', $v[0]));
```

this is it?